# iOS Firebase Twitter Login asks for Permission Every Time

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I am able to create an account and login via Twitter; however, with each login attempt the user is taken to a Twitter web page where they have to login with their credentials. Given this happens every time, it negates the value of this kind of social login. I have Facebook and Google logins working without this issue on Firebase. Below is the code used to login:

```
private func loginWithTwitter() {

        TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn { (session, error) in
            guard error == nil && session != nil else {
                self.spinner.dismiss()
                Utilities.displayAlert(title: "Login Error", msg: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Could not login with Twitter at this time.", controller: self)
                return
            }
            let credential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(withToken: session!.authToken, secret: session!.authTokenSecret)
            Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    self.spinner.dismiss()
                    self.present(self.sharedManager.getAlertWith(title: "Login Error", andMsg: error.localizedDescription), animated: true)
                    return
                }

                self.loadUserInfo()
            })
        }
    }
```

I should also add that I do have the use for logins box checked on the Twitter Developers page.

**UPDATE:**

Based on the post of Pratik below and here is a modified version that does seem to work. However, I am not sure if it's the right long-term answer. I wonder about token expiration for example. Thoughts on if there is a better way than this?

```
 private func loginWithTwitter() {

        let token = TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.authToken
        let secret = TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.authTokenSecret

        guard token != nil && secret != nil else {
            self.present(self.sharedManager.getAlertWith(title: "Login Error", andMsg: "Could not login with Twitter. Please try again."), animated: true)
            return
        }

        let credential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(withToken: token!, secret: secret!)
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.spinner.dismiss()
                self.present(self.sharedManager.getAlertWith(title: "Login Error", andMsg: error.localizedDescription), animated: true)
                return
            }

            self.loadUserInfo()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure with will help or not, but im using twitter login in my app and once i authenticate with twitter i used below function to when user open app again for validation.

```
func silentLoginWithTwitter()
{                
    let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
    let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "GET", urlString: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json", parameters: ["include_email": "true", "skip_status": "true"], error: nil)
    client.sendTwitterRequest(request, completion: { (response:URLResponse?, data:Data?, error:Error?) in

        if error == nil
        {
            // Open main page of application 
        }else
        {
            print("Error: Twitter : \(String(describing: error))")
            // Open Login page again
        }
    })
}
```

OR you can check session auth

```
if let authSession = TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.authToken {
        TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.isValidOauthToken(authSession)
    }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you for this. I actually used a modified version of what you presented to get the token and secret and then push those to the the Auth handler. That seems to have worked. I will upvote the answer but I am not sure if this is the right answer. Expiration of tokens is a question. Just not sure so want to see if anyone can chime in on that. Thanks again!